# @Async annotations being ignored

Tags: spring, asynchronous

I'm annotating methods with @Async but they seem to be ignored.

Here's my context file:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5-25"
        queue-capacity="100" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
    </bean>
```

When I create a runnable and auto wire taskExecutor, then call taskExecutor.execute(runnableThing) it works as expected.

However, Spring promises that if we just put @Async on a method it will functionally do the same thing. This is not happening for me (or at least the performance is nowhere near as good so I'm assuming it's not happening now that I think about it).

The method is very simple, here's some pseudo code:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

@Controller
public class MyClass{

//some auto wired stuff for db persistence

@Async
void doStuff(MyObject object){
//does some stuff with object
//write object to database
//send email
}

}
```

Any feedback on where else to look - I imagine this is some config thing but I can't figure it out

Comment: Please show the method that you are annotating along with it's class

Comment: `This is not happening for me` I don't understand what you think should happen and what actually happens in your case.

Comment: you might consider logging something in your async method to verify the name of the thread used during execution to make sure it is not working correctly.

Comment: Are you guys using the same xml specification? Did I get that right? I'll try the logging - though the performance doing this as a runnable instead of an annotation is significant.

Comment: Thanks much DavidA! Sometimes I need a nudge to do the obvious...threads are the same using the method. But I'm calling it from another method within the same class...someone else is indicating the calling method has to be in a separate class. I'll test that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but maybe this will help.

An `@Async` annotated method is meant to be run asynchronously. However, you still need to invoke it. It won't just run on its own. If you need it to run on its own, use `@Scheduled` with an appropriate configuration.

With `@Async`, get a reference to the bean that contains it and invoke the method on that bean. (Because of how proxying works, you won't be able to get this behavior by calling the method from within other methods of the same object.)

```
Bean yourBean = ...; // get it
yourBean.asyncMethod();
```

Comment: ah - this must be it, let me try that

Comment: @user2166452 [Here's](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) the chapter explaining proxies in Spring.

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios! That was it. I didn't realize you couldn't call an async method if it was in the same class. It makes sense because of proxying and use of reflection and all that...didn't occur to me out of the box

Comment: @user2166452 You can always refactor your code and move the `@Async` method to another bean (if it makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

Try `<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" proxy-target-class="true" />` and add CGLIB  as a dependency to the project

I am not so sure however that should be adding `@Async` to a controller's method. Best you add it on a service method that is called from the controller

Comment: Thanks! Yes, adding the async methods to services. Sorry I can't mark more than one answer correct...still figuring out stack overflow too

Comment: No problem! You can only mark one answer as correct, but you can upvote as many as you want :)